# Angular 2 pass var in component A to component B

Tags: angular

How do i get the slug into the items.component.ts
The url is like this http://domain.com/slug
So if i click on the nav item i want to pass the slug into the other component.

navbar.component.html:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li *ngFor="let item of items"><a (click)="changeParam(item.slug)" [routerLink]="[item.slug]" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">{{item.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
```

navbar.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
changeParam($slug) {

  this.sluggie = $slug;
}
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}
```

}

items.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit ,  Output } from '@angular/core';
import {ItemService} from "./item.service";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css'],
  providers: [ItemService]
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  id: string;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['slug'];
    });
  }


}
```

app-component.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <h1>
    {{title}}
    </h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-items></app-items>
</div>
```

Comment: How a nav and navbar related. Can you please add more code. What selectors do the components have. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Whithout knowing the selectors of the components in question I have no way to know where they are applied.

Comment: @Bas: Are you calling the items component inside the navbar component?

Comment: @HaHoang and Günter i put more detail.

Comment: I still can't see how the components are related. If the components are not in a direct parent-child relation or siblings (within the same template of a component) then use a shared service as explained in the docs I linked to above.

Comment: @günter Do you mean the app-component.ts? See updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass it from `NavbarComponent` to `ItemsComponent`s `id` you can use an output and a template variable

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @EventEmitter() slugChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  changeParam($slug) {
    this.sluggie = $slug;
    this.slugChange.emit($slug);
  }
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <app-navbar (slugChange)="items.id = $event"></app-navbar>
    <h1>
    {{title}}
    </h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-items #items></app-items>
</div>
```

This only works because `<app-navbar>` and `<app-items>` are in the same template. If this is not the case use a shared service.

Comment: Thanks but i am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_isScalar' of undefined

Comment: What is `_isScalar`? I assume this is somewhere in your code.

Comment: Is in the ArrayLikeObservable. It doesn't work :( I just want the slug if clicked on a nav item passing to the items.component

Comment: What does `ArrayLikeObservable` have to to with this question?

Comment: The code you propose doesnt work it gives this that error. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like to view the item details (`items.component.ts`) when you click on any link on the navbar (`navbar.component.ts`).

Please have a look at [Routing in angular2 revisited](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/14/routing-in-angular-2-revisited.html) or [Angular 2 Router](https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-router-d9e30599f9ea#.y717qm59w). I think they are good for you!

Comment: I dive into it, thnx